# What prior knowledge is required for proper Boost library use?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm still in the process of learning C++ concepts, but I'm fairly comfortable with pointers, references, Object Oriented Programming, and other programming basics. But I still need to learn more about templates, iterators, and regular expressions. Are there any other concepts I should have a firm grounding in to get the best use out of Boost libraries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as "proper" use of Boost. You use that part of Boost that helps you with your problem. For Boost Test, for example, you don't have to know much about anything specific. For Boost Graph or Algorithm, you should have a good grasp of templates.

Hence, there's no good way to answer your question. Look at the documentation of the library you want to use (Boost or otherwise), and if you think you can handle it, use it. Otherwise, come back here and ask a more specific question. ;-)

Comment: +1 Boost is collection of libraries, and each libraries as its own prerequisites. MPL, Fusion, Proto or Spirit are hairy but `boost::scoped_ptr` just works!

Answer (score 2):

You should know how templates and inheritancy works and read carefully the documentation of the module you are planning to use. It should be enough for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say since boost is really a collection of libraries. You should have knowledge of the problem domain before using a library. For example, what are threads and how to deal with them before using boost.thread.

As for C++ specific stuff:

1. You should know what the standard library already provides you.
2. Have a firm grasp on how to use templates